# Filebeat to Logstash - InvalidFrameProtocolException

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am trying to get filebeat to work with logstash. My filebeat is running on a Remote host and logstash on my Local. Getting below exception.

```
[2017-11-07T17:05:54,659][INFO ][logstash.agent  ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-11-07T17:13:27,889][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler] Exception: org.logstash.beats.BeatsParser$**InvalidFrameProtocolException**: Invalid Frame Type, received: 69, from: /192.168.50.167:41370
```

filebeat version: 5.6.3

logstash version: 5.6.3

logstash.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your filebeat config and a sample log event?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you did not set logstash in filebeat.yml as below

```
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["IP:5043"]
```